# Assign value to Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, global-variables

I am trying to assign value to javascript variable without refreshing page but its not working.
Consider example:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var id='';
        var source='';

        function assignvalue(_id,_source){

            //open div load in dialog box
               id = _id; 
               source = _source;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='load'></div>
    <script>
        _login.push(['login', 'callback_uri', 'http://localhost/Login/index/?source='+source+'&id='+id']);
    </script>

    <a href='' onclick="assignvalue('1','fromwhere');"></a>
</body>
```

In head define some variable globally and onclick of a tag I am opening div with load id and having global varible with new value.But new value is not assign to it below divs javascript.Any suggestion.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you are declaring two global variables `id` and `source`, but in your function definition you declare two local variables with the same name, so your desired changes to global variables are applied to local ones. Just rename the variables in the function definition.

For instance:

```
var id, source;

function assignvalue (_id, _source) {
    id = _id;
    source = _source;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question and work as per your solution.still its not working

Comment: script inside body loads first time when page is getting load and not after onclick of a tag that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring `id` and `source` twice: once in the global scope, and once as function parameters.

To overwrite the values of the global variables inside the function, you need to use a different name for the parameters.

Try

```
function assignvalue(_id, _source) {
  id = _id;
  source = _source;
}
```

To execute the `_login` function when the link is clicked, you could simply call it in `assignValue`:

```
function assignvalue(id, source) {
   _login.push(['login', 'callback_uri', 'http://localhost/Login/index/?source='+source+'&id='+id']);
}
```

In that case, it wouldn't be a bad idea to rename the function `assignvalue` to `login`

Comment: I have updated my question and work as per your solution.still its not working.

Comment: script inside body loads first time when page is getting load and not after onclick of a tag that is the problem

Comment: Sorry i cant do it because its an widget and it should be below div so that widget should load

Answer (score 0):

Because the way you pass value cannot be

```
function assignvalue(id,source)
```

cause id and source in the function here will become local variable instead.

Please replace the variable in parsing to other name so that it work, i.e

```
function assignvalue(passID,passSource){
    id = passID;
    source = passSource;
    console.log(id+" "+source);
}
```

then the global variable value will change.

Comment: THats basically the same answer as above only with different variable names and a console log

Comment: I have updated my question and work as per your solution.still its not working

Comment: script inside body loads first time when page is getting load and not after onclick of a tag that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, whatever you have written is correct.

But when you click on an **HyperLink** it will automatically refreshes the page.
Here you want to disable that auto refresh when you click on the Hyper link.For that you could amend your code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

      var id,source;
      function assignValue(_id,_source){
        id = _id;
        source = _source;
        alert(_id+" and also "+_source);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
     alert(id+" I am in Body "+source);
    </script>
    <a href="javascript:assignValue('1','fromWhere');">Hello</a>
</body>
```

**OR** alternatively you can try this

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>

      var id,source;
      function assignValue(_id,_source){
        id = _id;
        source = _source;
        alert(_id+" and also "+_source);
        return false;
      }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
     alert(id+" I am in Body "+source);
    </script>
    <a href="" onclick="return assignValue('1','fromWhere')">Hello</a>
</body>
```

**Extra Info:**
To override the default browser functionality, just you have to return false.
Not only here, almost you can apply this in many situations.
One such situation is disabling right click(simply) is just

```
oncontextmenu= return false;
```

and another such situation is disabling a KeyPress Event and so on.

So, you can apply this almost anywhere.